Is it possible for a magento 2 plugin to display a html written warning based on certain conditions?
These are two files i'm using to print a warning:
extra.html(https://i.sstatic.net/IYo7wvWk.png)
data.html(https://i.sstatic.net/TMabfFrJ.png)
This is what i'm getting but it's static, i want it to be conditional:
enter image description here
This warning has to be filtered between some sku's and categories to check compatibilities first.
If there are no compatibilities it should throw it.
i've made a plugiin myself, but it's not affecting the behavior of the text i'm adding to the cart.
My plugin:
<?php
namespace Webkul\MiniCart\Plugin\Checkout\CustomerData;

use Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart;
use Magento\Framework\Message\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Session\SessionManagerInterface;

class MiniCartPlug {
    protected $messageManager;
    protected $sessionManager;
    protected $compatibilities = [
        '951-0080' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['930-0026', '930-0027'], 'brand' => 'Glock', 'models' => ['17', '19', '43']],
        '951-0082' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['930-0024', '930-0025'], 'brand' => 'Taurus', 'models' => ['G2C', 'G3C', 'G3']],
        '951-0087' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['930-0026', '930-0027'], 'brand' => 'Sig Sauer', 'models' => ['P365 Macro']],
        '951-0079' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['930-0026', '930-0027'], 'brand' => 'Sig Sauer', 'models' => ['P365 Macro']],
        '951-0091' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['930-0038', '931-0038'], 'brand' => 'Springfield', 'models' => ['Hellcat Pro']],
        '951-0072' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['930-0024', '930-0025'], 'brand' => 'Sig Sauer', 'models' => ['P320']],
        '951-0090' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['930-0038', '931-0038'], 'brand' => 'Springfield', 'models' => ['Hellcat Pro']],
        '951-0077' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['930-0024', '930-0025'], 'brand' => 'Sig Sauer', 'models' => ['P365 Macro']],
        '951-0074' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['930-0026', '930-0027'], 'brand' => 'Sig Sauer', 'models' => ['P320']],
        '951-0068' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['930-0024', '930-0025'], 'brand' => 'Springfield', 'models' => ['Hellcat']],
        '951-0059' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['930-0026', '930-0027'], 'brand' => 'Sig Sauer', 'models' => ['P320']],
        '951-0065' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['930-0024', '930-0025'], 'brand' => 'Sig Sauer', 'models' => ['P365 Macro']],
        '951-0067' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['930-0024', '930-0025'], 'brand' => 'Taurus', 'models' => ['G2C', 'G3C', 'G3']],
        '951-0066' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['930-0024', '930-0025'], 'brand' => 'Springfield', 'models' => ['Hellcat Pro']],
        '951-0069' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['930-0026', '930-0027'], 'brand' => 'Glock', 'models' => ['17', '19', '43']],
        '951-0053' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['930-0024', '930-0025'], 'brand' => 'Springfield', 'models' => ['Hellcat']],
        '951-0063' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['930-0026', '930-0027'], 'brand' => 'Taurus', 'models' => ['G2C', 'G3C', 'G3']],
        '951-0054' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['930-0024', '930-0025'], 'brand' => 'Taurus', 'models' => ['G2C', 'G3C', 'G3']],
        '951-0055' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['930-0024', '930-0025'], 'brand' => 'Springfield', 'models' => ['Hellcat Pro']],
        '951-0057' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['930-0026', '930-0027'], 'brand' => 'Glock', 'models' => ['17', '19', '43']],
        '951-0058' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['930-0026', '930-0027'], 'brand' => 'Springfield', 'models' => ['Hellcat Pro']],
        '952-0003' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['930-0001', '930-0006', '930-0007'], 'brand' => 'Glock', 'models' => ['19', '19X', '45', '23', '29', '32', '38']],
        '952-0007' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['930-0001', '930-0006', '930-0007'], 'brand' => 'Palmetto State Armory', 'models' => [' PS9 Dagger']],
        '951-0081' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0026'], 'brand' => 'Taurus', 'models' => ['G3', 'G3c', 'G3X', 'G2c', 'G2 PT111']],
        '951-0004' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0026'], 'brand' => 'Taurus', 'models' => ['G3', 'G3c', 'G3X', 'G2c', 'G2 PT111']],
        '951-0011' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0029', '912-0079'], 'brand' => 'Springfield', 'models' => ['Hellcat/Hellcat OSP (NOT RDP)']],
        '951-0003' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0026'], 'brand' => 'Taurus', 'models' => ['G3', 'G3c', 'G3X', 'G2c', 'G2 PT111']],
        '951-0093' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0030', '912-0078'], 'brand' => 'Sig Sauer', 'models' => ['P365 XL']],
        '951-0092' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0030', '912-0078'], 'brand' => 'Sig Sauer', 'models' => ['P365 XL']],
        '951-0071' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0045'], 'brand' => 'Ruger', 'models' => ['MAX9']],
        '951-0070' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0049', '912-0050'], 'brand' => 'Palmetto State Armory', 'models' => ['']],
        '951-0061' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0049', '912-0050'], 'brand' => 'Palmetto State Armory', 'models' => ['']],
        '951-0021' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0045'], 'brand' => 'Ruger', 'models' => ['MAX9']],
        '951-0031' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0077'], 'brand' => 'Springfield', 'models' => ['Hellcat PRO']],
        '951-0015' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0043'], 'brand' => 'Taurus', 'models' => ['GX4']],
        '951-0019' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0030', '912-0078'], 'brand' => 'Sig Sauer', 'models' => ['P365']],
        '951-0028' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0030', '912-0078'], 'brand' => 'Sig Sauer', 'models' => ['P365']],
        '951-0086' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0003'], 'brand' => 'Taurus', 'models' => ['G3', 'G3c', 'G3X', 'G2c', 'G2 PT111']],
        '951-0027' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0030', '912-0078'], 'brand' => 'Sig Sauer', 'models' => ['P365']],
        '951-0010' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0071'], 'brand' => 'Ruger', 'models' => ['LCP MAX']],
        '951-0013' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0071'], 'brand' => 'Ruger', 'models' => ['LCP MAX']],
        '951-0022' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0045'], 'brand' => 'Ruger', 'models' => ['MAX9']],
        '951-0012' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0030', '912-0078'], 'brand' => 'Sig Sauer', 'models' => ['P365']],
        '951-0009' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0071'], 'brand' => 'Ruger', 'models' => ['LCP MAX']],
        '951-0014' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0071'], 'brand' => 'Ruger', 'models' => ['LCP MAX']],
        '951-0026' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0030', '912-0078'], 'brand' => 'Sig Sauer', 'models' => ['P365']],
        '951-0084' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0003'], 'brand' => 'Taurus', 'models' => ['G3', 'G3c', 'G3X', 'G2c', 'G2 PT111']],
        '951-0020' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0071'], 'brand' => 'Ruger', 'models' => ['LCP MAX']],
        '951-0033' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0077'], 'brand' => 'Springfield', 'models' => ['Hellcat PRO']],
        '951-0037' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0045'], 'brand' => 'Ruger', 'models' => ['MAX9']],
        '951-0040' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0071'], 'brand' => 'Ruger', 'models' => ['LCP MAX']],
        '951-0073' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0045'], 'brand' => 'Ruger', 'models' => ['MAX9']],
        '951-0041' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0077'], 'brand' => 'Springfield', 'models' => ['Hellcat PRO']],
        '951-0051' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0030', '912-0078'], 'brand' => 'Sig Sauer', 'models' => ['P365 XL']],
        '951-0064' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0030', '912-0078'], 'brand' => 'Sig Sauer', 'models' => ['P365 XL']],
        '951-0075' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0045'], 'brand' => 'Ruger', 'models' => ['MAX9']],
        '951-0076' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0030', '912-0078'], 'brand' => 'Sig Sauer', 'models' => ['P365 XL']],
        '951-0088' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['912-0071'], 'brand' => 'Ruger', 'models' => ['LCP MAX']],
        '951-0083' => ['compatible_accessories' => ['930-0015'], 'brand' => '', 'models' => ['']]
    ];

    // IDs for the categories "Lasers & Lights" and "Holsters"
    const LASERS_LIGHTS_CATEGORY_ID = 3; // ID real de la categoría "Lasers & Lights"
    const HOLSTERS_CATEGORY_ID = 2;      // ID real de la categoría "Holsters"

    public function __construct(
        ManagerInterface $messageManager,
        SessionManagerInterface $sessionManager
    ) {
        $this->messageManager = $messageManager;
        $this->sessionManager = $sessionManager;
    }

    public function beforeAddProduct(Cart $subject, $productInfo, $requestInfo = null)
    {
        // Get products that are already in the cart
        $items = $subject->getQuote()->getAllItems();
        $productToAddSku = $productInfo->getSku();
        $categoryToAdd = $this->getProductCategory($productInfo);

        // Only proceed if the product belongs to one of the categories we are monitoring
        if ($categoryToAdd == self::LASERS_LIGHTS_CATEGORY_ID || $categoryToAdd == self::HOLSTERS_CATEGORY_ID) {
            foreach ($items as $item) {
                $skuInCart = $item->getSku();
                $categoryInCart = $this->getProductCategory($item->getProduct());

                // Check if the categories are different and if they are incompatible according to our array
                if ($categoryToAdd !== $categoryInCart && !$this->isCompatible($skuInCart, $productToAddSku)) {
                    // Guardamos el mensaje de advertencia en la sesión
                    $warningMessage = __("El producto %1 no es compatible con el producto %2 en tu carrito.", $productToAddSku, $skuInCart);
                    $this->sessionManager->setCompatibilityWarning($warningMessage);
                }
            }
        }

        // IMPORTANT: Make sure to return the arguments
        return [$productInfo, $requestInfo];
    }

    protected function isCompatible($sku1, $sku2)
    {
        // Check if product 1 has compatible accessories in the compatibility array
        if (isset($this->compatibilities[$sku1]) && in_array($sku2, $this->compatibilities[$sku1]['compatible_accessories'])) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function getProductCategory($product)
    {
        // Get the first category of the product
        $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
        if (!empty($categoryIds)) {
            return $categoryIds[0];
        }
        return null;
    }
}



Yes, it is definitely possible to display an HTML warning message in Magento 2 based on certain conditions using a plugin. You can achieve this by leveraging a custom plugin (also known as an interceptor) that modifies the output or behavior of a Magento class or method.
